# how to install depth image laser scan on fuerte

Tags: ros, laser, scan, ros-fuerte, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys, i'm trying to install depthimage_to_laserscan stack by writing

> git clone "git link that i cannot post"

> cd depthimage_to_laserscan

> rosmake

> [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
> [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['depthimage_to_laserscan']
> [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['depthimage_to_laserscan']
> [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/d4n/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130420-144925
> [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['depthimage_to_laserscan'] to:
> ['depthimage_to_laserscan']
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> depthimage_to_laserscan [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< depthimage_to_laserscan ROS_NOBUILD in package depthimage_to_laserscan
> No Makefile in package depthimage_to_laserscan
> [ rosmake ] Results:
> [ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 0 failures.
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
> [ rosmake ] /home/d4n/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130420-144925

but it says

then trying to "rosrun"

> rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/dept/image_raw

says:

> [rospack] Error: stack/package depthimage_to_laserscan not found

I don't know what I'm doing wrong

I know that probably could be a simple things that I forgot to do.

thank a lot for any help

EDIT 1:
thanks everybody

i tried as suggested

> cd ~/my_ros_directory_thats_in_ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

> git clone -b fuerte-devel https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan.git

> rospack profile

> rosmake depthimage_to_laserscan

it results

> Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests depthimage_to_laserscan
> [rospack] Error: package/stack depthimage_to_laserscan depends on non-existent >package sensor_msgs

then following this http://answers.ros.org/question/12715/how-do-i-install-sensor_msgs-package/

the shell tell me

> ros-fuerte-common-msgs is already the newest version.

so, I will migrate to groovy or there is still something to try?

EDIT 2: after a lot of trying I move to groovy and the stack work pretty well.

Thanks for helping me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61205/how-to-install-depth-image-laser-scan-on-fuerte/) by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-04-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2013-04-20**:
Did you do this all in a directory which is in your ROS package path?  (echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to see what the path is.)

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-04-20**:
yep, I exported the path by typing:     export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/ros/ros-pkg:/home/d4n/depthimage_to_laserscan

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-04-21**:
Oh, and don't forget to always export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/ros/ros-pkg:/home/d4n/depthimage_to_laserscan:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH since you want to append the variable, not replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a catkin package, not rosmake.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials

Also, likely what is easier:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-depthimage-to-laserscan
```

---

For fuerte (and rosmake), besides my recommendation to update to Groovy, you could run pointcloud_to_laserscan from ros-groovy-turtlebot-apps OR do the following:

```
cd ~/my_ros_directory_thats_in_ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
git clone -b fuerte-devel https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan.git
rospack profile
rosmake depthimage_to_laserscan
```

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-04-23**:
I tried pointcloud_to_laserscan without great results, so I decide to try depthimage_to_laserscan